# Game Center unable to load score in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I have been using the apple example GKTapper (from 2010) to manage scores for a long time. It stopped working in iOS6. I am unsure what to do because I added the following snippet and the leaderboard still says "UNABLE TO LOAD". (I was able to login, but no score is loaded). PLEASE HELP!

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] \
compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

- (void) authenticateLocalUser
{

if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
{

 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
 {

     [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
      {
          [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processGameCenterAuth:) withArg: NULL error: error];
      }];
 }else{

     [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
         if (!error && viewcontroller)
         {
             [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processGameCenterAuth:) withArg: NULL error: error];
         }
         else
         {
             //do nothing
         }
     })];
 }
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS6 you have to present the UIViewController yourself. Is that being done in processGameCenterAuth: ?

IOW you need code something like:

```
[self presentViewController: viewcontroller];
```

within the block.